# problema en proyecto de descuentos en C

Tags: c

estoy tratando de hacer un programa en C (puede ser en JAva tambien) que me pida ingresar un mes y un precio, y luego que muestre un descuento del 50% al mes siguiente ingresado, luego un 40% al otro mes y así hasta no tener ningún descuento. Ejemplo: Usuario ingresa Febrero 1000 y el sistema devuelve: Marzo 500, Abril 600, Mayo 700, Junio 800, Julio 900, Agosto 1000. Empece con el pedido de datos, pero me trabo en la logica, estoy seguro que debo hacer un ciclo que se ejecute 5 veces, pero no me sale. Desde ya muchas gracias

```
void main()
{
    char mes;
    int arancel,descuento,i;
    printf("Ingrese Mes y Ultimo Arancel cobrado\n\n"); 
    printf("Ingrese Mes:\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",&mes);
    printf("Ingrese ultimo arancel cobrado en dicho mes:\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&arancel);
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenido! No tengas miedo de (editar tu pregunta e) incluir el ciclo que intentaste implementar, que seguro es más fácil para otros ayudarte viendo todo el ejercicio que probaste. De paso, incluye los errores que salieron o por qué ves que no te funcionó.

Comment: También trata de limitar tu pregunta a un solo lenguaje, decídete xD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Observaciones a tu código:**

En primer lugar, ese `fflush(stdin)` es **totalmente** innecesario, con el `scanf()` es suficiente. También debo decir que definir `mes` con solo `char`, permite almacenar un solo carácter. Cuando se trata de strings hay que asignarle una longitud máxima  a la variable `char`, esto se puede lograr a través de una constante (para fines prácticos), o con la longitud directamente. En ejemplo:

```
#define SIZE 10

void main() {
    char nombre[10] //Ambos son los mismo
    char nombre[SIZE]
}
```

La diferencia entre definir una constante o no, es que se puede usar la misma longitud para todos los strings de nuestro programa (invocándola con la palabra).

**En camino a la solución:**

Para realizar tu tarea se ocupa un ciclo `for`, pero para dar una salida por pantalla más adecuada es mejor implementar condicionales para imprimir diferentes mensajes (al final explico el por qué).

```
for (int i = 0;i < 5;i = i + 1) {
    descuento = (arancel / 100) * (50 + ((i + 1) * 10));

    printf("%i mes(es) despues: %d \n",i + 1,descuento);
}
```

Con esto hacemos impresión (general) de los elementos que se desean imprimir, la formula de descuento es así (un poco rara), con el fin de contrarrestar el primer `i = 0`. De lo contrario obtendríamos un "0 meses". ://

También es necesario incluir la librería estándar de entrada y salida, para tener acceso a `printf()` y `scanf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h> //Al principio del código
```

**¿Por qué el programa sería mejor con condicionales?**

La razón de porque creo que se deberían de implementar condicionales es porque si te fijas puse `mes(es)`, para generalizar singular y plural. Con un `if i == 1 {}` se podría imprimir un mensaje diferente para cuando pasa solo se trata de un mes.

Espero haberte ayudado ;)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias gabrielcoronel !!! estaba trabado con el ciclo FOR, yo queria hacer un ciclo que vaya muliplicando por 0.5, despues 0.4, 0.3, 0.2 y 0.1 (al arancel ingresado)  pero no me estaba resultando, me ayudaste muchisimo! Muchas gracias nuevamente!!!

Comment: @MatiasAbaro, la manera de agradecer, no solo a mí si no a cualquier persona que responda tu pregunta, es aceptarla (esto se hace marcando el check abajo de las flechas de puntuación).

Comment: Gracias! No sabia como hacerlo, listo!